# Difference between these two update SQL statements in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

What's the difference between these two update SQL statements in Oracle

First:

```
UPDATE t1 
    SET    col1 = 'Y' 
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   t2 
               WHERE  t1.p1 = t2.p1 
                      AND t1.p2 = t2.p2 
                      AND t2.col3 = 'a' 
                      AND t1.p1 = 'b' 
                      AND t1.p2 = 'c')
```

Second:

```
UPDATE t1 
SET    col1 = 'Y' 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM   t2 
           WHERE  t1.p1 = t2.p1 
                  AND t1.p2 = t2.p2 
                  AND t2.col3 = 'a') 
   AND t1.p1 = 'b' 
   AND t1.p2 = 'c'
```

Comment: the update sql in Sybase should be: 
update t1 set col1 = 'Y' from t1, t2 where t1.p1= t2.p1 and t1.p2= t2.p2 and t2.col3= 'a' and t1.p1='b' and t1.p2='c' I am not sure the 2 sqls above are equivalent or which one is right...

Comment: they are the same in terms of result, however second is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

there is no difference at all - they have the same meaning

Comment: Is it the equivalent of update t1 set col1 = 'Y' from t1, t2 where t1.p1= t2.p1 and t1.p2= t2.p2 and t2.col3= 'a' and t1.p1='b' and t1.p2='c' ?

Comment: without checking it explicitly the result should be same